# Prove radius of convergence of a power series $=1$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Q) Let $X_1,X_2,..$ be i.i.d. and not $\equiv 0$. Show that the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n\geq 1}X_nz^n$ is $1$ a.s. or $0$ a.s. according as $E\text{ log}^+|X_1|<\infty \text{ or } = \infty$, where $\text{log}^+x = \text{max(log }x,0)$ and radius of convergence $r$ is $r = \text{sup}\{c:\sum|X_n|c^n<\infty\}$.

If $E\text{ log}^+|X_1|=\infty$, it is relatively simple because $$\sum_{n\geq 1}P(\text{ log}^+|X_n|>\epsilon n) = \infty \text{ for any }\epsilon<\infty\implies |X_n|>e^{\epsilon n}\text{ i.o.}\implies r=0$$

If $E\text{ log}^+|X_1|<\infty$, using the same logic $$\sum_{n\geq 1}P(\text{ log}^+|X_n|>\epsilon n) = \infty \text{ for any }\epsilon>0\implies |X_n|\leq e^{ n\epsilon}\text{ for large n}$$

May I know how that implies $r=1$? i.e. how is $\sum_{n\geq 1}|X_n|<\infty$ ? It is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2949571/exercise-2-5-8-durretts-book) that $\text{limsup log }|X_n|/n = 0$ which I understand but am not sure why the sum above is $<\infty$? Thanks.

Comment: That sum is divergent a.s. but it isn't what radius 1 means anyway... (remember the supremum of a set need not be an element of that set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $|z| <1$. choose $\epsilon >0 $ such that $e^{\epsilon} |z| <1$. Then $|X_nz^{n}| \leq e^{n\epsilon} |z|^{n}$ for $n$ sufficiently large  and $\sum  e^{n\epsilon} |z|^{n}<\infty$ so the series converges almost surely for $|z| <1$.

If $|z| >1$ then $|X_nz^{n}| $ does not tend to $0$ with positive probability: $P(|X_n|>\frac 1 {|z|^{n}})=P(|X_1|>\frac 1 {|z|^{n}})\to P(X_1 \neq 0)>0)$ because $X_1$ is not degenerate. Hence the given series diverges with positive probability. But  a series of independent random variables converge with probability $0$ or $1$. Hence the series diverges with probability $1$ whenever $|z|>1$. It follows that the radius of convergence is $1$ with probability $1$.